Regex для парсинга строки, зная первое слово и последнее
Я столкнулся с проблемой того, что мне необходимо парсить строку, которая выглядит как-то так:
Overview:
текст

другой абзац текста

Thread Updated: 0000-00-00

И сущность проблемы в том, что мне необходимо парсить все, что находится в этом блоке, но на каждой странице количество абзацев может отличаться, но Overview и Thread Updated всегда на своих местах. Поэтому я хотел подобрать такой Regex, чтобы оно удовлетворяло моим условия.
Я пытался использовать что-то подобное: "Overview:\n(.*?)(?=Thread Updated), но он проходит по всем символам только первого абзаца.
Поэтому мне бы хотелось узнать:

Какой Regex тут подойдет
И можно ли как-то ускорить процесс парсинга (потому что с данным Regex строка проходится за 500-1000 шагов из-за посимвольного прохода)


какой результат ты хочешь получить для приведенного примера?

@Grundy мне необходимо получить все, что внутри в диапазоне от Overview до Thread Updated, без разницы включительно или нет

@d1rknwh1te3, вот тебе в помощь - https://sourceforge.net/projects/regextest/ (написано на C#, требует .NET 3.0, но если пересобрать, то и не будет)

Изменил теги, так как ответ написан и принят на JS.

@Ingvar https://regex101.com


мне необходимо парсить все, что находится в этом блоке, но на каждой странице количество абзацев может отличаться, но Overview и Thread Updated всегда на своих местах

Предложу такой вариант...


const s = `Overview:
текст1

другой абзац текста1

Thread Updated: 0000-00-00

Overview:
текст2

другой абзац текста2

Thread Updated: 0000-00-00`
const r = /(?<=Overview:\n)(?:.|\n)*?(?=\nThread Updated)/g
console.log(s.match(r))




проверил этот вариант на нескольких примерах, все отлично сходится и работает, спасибо
